# $L \cap V = \overline{L} \cap V$ when $L\cap V$ is closed in $V$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $E$ be a topological space and $L, V \subset E$, $V$ open, and $L \cap V$ closed in $V$, then $\overline{L} \cap V = L \cap V$.

Attempt:
$L \cap V$ closed in $V$ implies $L \cap V = F \cap V$ for some closed $F \subset E$.  Now $F \supset L \cap V$.

---

$\ \overline{A} = (\bigcap_{F_1 \supset B} F_1) \cup (\bigcap_{F_2 \supset C} F_2)$ when $A = B \cup C$.  Proof: clearly $LHS \subset RHS$.
$$
(\bigcap_{F_1 \supset B} F_1) \cup (\bigcap_{F_2 \supset C} F_2) = \bigcap_{F_1 \supset B, \ F_2\supset C} F_1 \cup F_2
$$

the right side $\bigcup$ including $F_1 = F_2 = F \supset A$.

---

Now $\overline{L} = \overline{(L\cap V)} \cup \overline{(L \setminus V)}$.   Now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Cl_V(A) = V \cap Cl_E(A)$, so $L \cap V = V \cap F = Cl_V(L\cap V) = V \cap \overline{ (L \cap V)}$.

$\overline{L \cap V} = \overline{L} \cap \overline{V}$.  Done.